# Parsing and Analysing few GBs data

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory, scalability

I am looking for an approach to analyse custom log files.

I have right now implemented using LINQ and C#.NET. It only works on log files of size upto 500MB.

Each line of the log file is made in to an object that looks like

```
public class Metrics
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Metrics1 { get; set; }
    public string Metrics2 { get; set; }
                :
                :
    public string Metrics9 { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<Metrics> MetricsList = new List<Metrics>();
```

---

MetricsList is populated.
Various LINQ queries are run on MetricsList to provide useful analytics.
It is observed that a Metrics object needs 300 bytes. I have approximately 4 million lines in 500MB log files which makes the size of MetricsList alone consuming more than 1GB of program memory.

My requirement is to parse and analyse files with size upto 2 GB which looks like going to consume 4 GB of memory.

Any better approaches or alternatives using Windows, Microsoft Technologies and any Open Source Libraries.

Comment: You'll likely have to stream the data in. Read one metric (or a chunk of metrics) at a time, dispose them from memory, and move onto the next.

Comment: How are you reading the lines? You can use a `Streamreader` or `File.ReadLines` to read one line after each other instead of all (f.e. `File.ReadAllLines`). You should also have a look at the [`MemoryMappedFile`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx). _Memory-mapped files enable programmers to work with extremely large files because memory can be managed concurrently, and they allow complete, random access to a file without the need for seeking. Memory-mapped files can also be shared across multiple processes_

Comment: "I have a limitation of using Windows and Microsoft Technologies", why do you see that as limitation? What are the technologies you have otherwise?

Comment: @NasmiSabeer: I don't know what you're referring to since both Chris and myself are not speaking of non-ms technologies, are we?

Comment: @Tim my point here is why the poster sees Window & Microsoft technologies as limited. And what are the other technologies he thinks this can be done without any limitation. I think you misunderstood my comment!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! Just edited my question and removed the limitation part.

Comment: LINQ just stops at 500MB?   Do you have repeating values in the metrics?  If so create a Dictionary<int, string> and in the List just store the int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar task using SQlite. Install System.Data.SQLite NuGet (optional: I have used Dapper NuGet as a very efficient micro-ORM too) and then you have a very good tool for performing queries and generating your reports. The only thing that you may not like is that you have to write SQL instead of LINQ (Although there is LINQ for SQLite too; but I have not used it).

This way that memory consumption will go away too.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't want to store files like that in memory (unless you have enough of course), but process the data as you parse the file. I'd simply install more memory and set the solution to 64-bit probably...

However, if that is not an option, you can always optimize memory usage a bit. .NET stores strings as char[] where a char is basically a 2-byte short. You can easily save a lot of memory by simply not storing it as char[] but as byte[] using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes.

Also, each string or byte[] consumes 24 bytes (16 for the object itself, 8 for the pointer) in a 64-bit environment. That can add up if you have a lot of small strings. Instead of storing them as strings, you can also store a single byte[] and do the parsing in the getters.

So to conclude my advice is: buy more memory or process the data as you read/need it.

**[Update+1]**

Just noticed that you use a List. The easiest way to process-as-you-go is to read the file as IEnumerable and use Linq on that. Don't put it in a list first. E.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<Metric> ReadFile()
{
    string s;
    while ((s=myFileReader.ReadLine())!=null)
    {
        yield return Parse(s);
    }
}

int someAnalysis = ReadFile().Sum((a)=>(a.Metric1.Length)); // or whatever you do
```

**[Update+2]**

Oh I have another trick for you. Reading files can be a pain with performance, since file IO relatively sucks. So instead of using the IEnumeration trick from above, you can also use a compressed stream to store all the data in memory - and then use that during processing instead of the file.

For the people that are wondering if I'm serious about this weird solution: this is a frequently used technique when you're building search technology and databases, simply because having more in (fast) memory means having less (slow) disk IO. Further, a log file will probably compress very nicely.

So Read file && flatestream on top of a memorystream. Then read that for Linq in the way discussed above (again, flatestream on top of memorystream).